# Compute difficult integral $\int \frac{dx}{2 + x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}$

Tags: integration

To solve the integral
$$I = \int \frac{dx}{2 + x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}$$
I have tried several things, such as $t = \arcsin x$, because $\cos(\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. If I am not wrong, we can conclude with this variable change
$$
I = \int \frac{\cos t\,dt}{2 + \sin t + \cos t}
$$
but if it were correct, how could I go on?

Comment: Weierstrass substituition?

Comment: You may put $t = tan(x/2)$ and then it will be sufficient to integrate a rational function of t by standard methods, see e.g. https://www.math24.net/integration-rational-functions/#:~:text=P(x)Q(x)%3DF(x,of%20integrals%20of%20simpler%20functions.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int\frac{dx}{2+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Substitute $x= \sin 2u;\;dx=2\cos 2u$

$$\int \frac{2\cos (2 u)}{2+\sin (2 u)+\cos (2 u)} \, du$$
$$\int \frac{2\cos ^2 u-2\sin ^2 u}{2-\sin ^2 u+\cos ^2 u+2 \sin u \cos u}\,du$$
$$\int \frac{2\cos ^2 u-2\sin ^2 u}{\sin ^2 u+3 \cos ^2 u+2 \sin u \cos u}\,du$$
divide numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 u$
$$\int \frac{2-2\tan ^2 u}{\tan ^2 u +2 \tan u +3}\,du$$
substitute $\tan u = t\to dt=\frac{du}{1+u^2}$
$$\int \frac{2-2t^2}{\left(t^2+1\right) \left(t^2+2 t+3\right)}\,dt$$
using partial fraction
$$\int \left(\frac{1-t}{t^2+1}+\frac{t-1}{t^2+2 t+3}\right)\,dt$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(-\log \left(t^2+1\right)+\log \left(t^2+2 t+3\right)+2 \arctan t-2 \sqrt{2} \arctan\left(\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+C$$
$t=\tan u$ and $x=\sin 2u$ we have $t=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$
$$\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+x+2\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)-\sqrt{2} \arctan\left(\frac{-\sqrt{1-x^2}+x+1}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)+C$$

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you

Comment: @joseabp91 There was a typo. I fixed it. Now it is correct

Answer (score 2):

*Bioche's rules* say you should set  $\;u=\tan \frac t2,\enspace \mathrm du=\frac12(1+u^2)\,\mathrm dt$, whence the integral of a rational function
$$\int\frac{2(1-u^2)\,\mathrm du}{(1+u^2)(u^2+2u+3)},$$
which is easily calculated using partial fractions decomposition.

*Some more details*: using the half angle formulæ, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\cos t}{2 + \sin t + \cos t}\,\mathrm dt&=\frac{\cfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}{2+\cfrac{2u}{1+u^2}+\cfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\,\frac{2\,\mathrm du}{1+u^2} \\
&=\frac{2(1-u^2)}{(1+u^2)\bigl(2(1+u^2)+2u+1-u^2\bigr)} \\
&=\frac{2(1-u^2)}{(1+u^2)\bigl(u^2+2u+3\bigr)}. \\
\end{align}

Comment: I wonder if the initial step in OP is indeed correct. Shouldn't the integrand be $\frac{\cos t}{2 + \sin t + |\cos t|}$?

Comment: It is correct because $\arcsin x\in\bigl[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi 2\bigr] $, and on this interval $\cos t\ge0$.

Comment: The result is [very simple](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-u%5E2%29%2F%28%281%2Bu%5E2%29%281%2Bu%29%5E2%29), $\ln\cos(\tfrac{\arcsin x}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4})+C$.

Comment: How do we conclude that the integral is $\int \frac{(1 - u^2) du}{(1 + u^2)(1 + u)^2}$?

Comment: @joseabp91; There was an error in my initial computation. I've fixed it and added some details.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Bernard ! I took the freedom of finishing the calculations. I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: Hi Claude ! No problem! When I wrote my answer, it was really too late  to begin the final computation…

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* gives:

$$\frac{1}{8} \left(4 \sin ^{-1}(x)+4 \sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}
   (x+1)\right)+\frac{2 i \left(i+2 \sqrt{2}\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(-16+6 i
   \sqrt{2}\right) x^4-2 i \left(9 \sqrt{1-2 i \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}+10 \left(-3
   i+\sqrt{2}\right)\right) x^3-i \left(36 \sqrt{1-2 i \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}+79
   \sqrt{2}-20 i\right) x^2+3 \left(-9 i \sqrt{1-2 i \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}-20 i
   \sqrt{2}+20\right) x-9 i \sqrt{2}+36}{\left(66 i+32 \sqrt{2}\right) x^4+16 \left(14
   i+3 \sqrt{2}\right) x^3+\left(253 i-14 \sqrt{2}\right) x^2-48 \left(-2
   i+\sqrt{2}\right) x-18 \sqrt{2}+9 i}\right)}{\sqrt{1-2 i \sqrt{2}}}+2 \sqrt{1+2 i
   \sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \left(8+3 i \sqrt{2}\right) x^4+2 \left(-9 i
   \sqrt{1+2 i \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}-10 i \sqrt{2}+30\right) x^3+\left(-36 i \sqrt{1+2 i
   \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}-79 i \sqrt{2}+20\right) x^2-3 i \left(9 \sqrt{1+2 i \sqrt{2}}
   \sqrt{1-x^2}+20 \left(-i+\sqrt{2}\right)\right) x-9 i \sqrt{2}-36}{\left(-66 i+32
   \sqrt{2}\right) x^4+16 \left(-14 i+3 \sqrt{2}\right) x^3-\left(253 i+14
   \sqrt{2}\right) x^2-48 \left(2 i+\sqrt{2}\right) x-9 \left(i+2
   \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)+2 \log \left(2 x^2+4 x+3\right)-\frac{\left(i+2
   \sqrt{2}\right) \log \left(4 \left(2 x^2+4 x+3\right)^2\right)}{\sqrt{1-2 i
   \sqrt{2}}}-\frac{\left(-i+2 \sqrt{2}\right) \log \left(4 \left(2 x^2+4
   x+3\right)^2\right)}{\sqrt{1+2 i \sqrt{2}}}+\frac{\left(i+2 \sqrt{2}\right) \log
   \left(\left(2 x^2+4 x+3\right) \left(-2 \left(-i+\sqrt{2}\right) x^2+2 i
   \left(\sqrt{2-4 i \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}+2\right) x+2 i \sqrt{2-4 i \sqrt{2}}
   \sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \sqrt{2}+3 i\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-2 i \sqrt{2}}}+\frac{\left(-i+2
   \sqrt{2}\right) \log \left(-\left(2 x^2+4 x+3\right) \left(2 \left(i+\sqrt{2}\right)
   x^2+2 i \left(\sqrt{2+4 i \sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-x^2}+2\right) x+2 i \sqrt{2+4 i \sqrt{2}}
   \sqrt{1-x^2}-2 \sqrt{2}+3 i\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1+2 i \sqrt{2}}}\right)$$

which strongly suggests no clean simplification.

Comment: Judging by @Bernard's answer, the real lesson is Mathematica has a weakspot. [Wolfram Alpha is a _bit_ nicer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%282%2Bx%2Bsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29).

Comment: Thanks, but I'll defer judgement until @Bernard completes the integral.

Comment: Not really. Look at my answer: I used *Mathematica* to simplify. It's correct, I verified 3 times the derivative :)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. I completed the integral starting from Bernard's answer

Answer (score 1):

Continue with $x=\sin t$

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{2 + x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx=\int \frac{\cos t}{2 + \sin t + \cos t}dt\\
= &\ \frac12\int \left(1+ \frac{\cos t-\sin t}{2 + \sin t + \cos t}-
\frac{2}{2 + \sin t + \cos t} \right)dt\\
=& \ \frac12t +\frac12 \ln(2 + \sin t + \cos t) -\sqrt2\tan^{-1} \frac{\tan\frac t2+1}{\sqrt2}\\
=&\ \frac12\sin^{-1}x+\frac12 \ln\left(2 + x+ \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) -\sqrt2\tan^{-1} \frac{1+x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x \sqrt2}
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think this is right because your integrand has $\cos t$ in the denominator, which can have negative values, while $\sqrt{1 - x^2} \geq 0$.  Right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - the sub $\sin t=x\in (-1,1)$ ensures $t\in (-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. So, $\cos t>0$.

Comment: Huh?  The original problem is an *indefinite* integral.  How would your "solution" apply if the OP wanted to use the solution for a definite integral such as $\int\limits_{x= - 50}^{20} f(x)\ dx$?  You can't simply employ a substitution that does not embrace the full domain.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - note that the domain of the integrand is $|x|<1$ due to $1-x^2 >0$.

Comment: Ummm... there's no restriction that the integrand is real (and there were several opportunities or ways in which to specify that, but weren't).  Of course that is why *Mathematica* gave the complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Euler substitution
$$tx-1=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$t=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$
$$x=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}$$
$$dx=\frac{2(1-t^2)}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{2+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int\frac{1}{2+(t+1)\frac{2t}{t^2+1}-1}\frac{2(1-t^2)}{(t^2+1)^2}dt=\int\frac{2(1-t^2)dt}{(3t^2+2t+1)(t^2+1)}$$$$=-\int\frac{t+1}{t^2+1}dt+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{6t+2}{3t^2+2t+1}dt+\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{dt}{(t+\frac{1}{3})^2+\frac{2}{9}}$$$$=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(t^2+1)-\arctan(t)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(3t^2+2t+1)+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\frac{2}{9}}\arctan\left(\frac{t+\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{9}}\right)+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{3t^2+2t+1}{t^2+1}\right)-\arctan(t)+3\arctan\left(\frac{9t+3}{2}\right)+C$$
where $t=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Using @Bernard solution
$$y=\frac{2(1-u^2)}{(1+u^2)\bigl(u^2+2u+3\bigr)}$$ using partial fractions
$$y=-\frac{1+i}{2(u-i)}-\frac{1-i}{2 (u+ i)}+\frac{\sqrt{2}+2 i}{2 \left(\sqrt{2} u+\sqrt{2}-2 i\right)}+\frac{\sqrt{2}-2 i}{2 \left(\sqrt{2} u+\sqrt{2}+2 i\right)}$$
$$\int y\,du=\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \log (-2 u+2 i)\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \log (2 u+2 i)+$$
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}+2 i\right) \log \left(\sqrt{2} u+\sqrt{2}-2 i\right)}{2
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-2 i\right) \log \left(\sqrt{2} u+\sqrt{2}+2 i\right)}{2
   \sqrt{2}}$$

Now, recombining everything
$$\int y\,du=\tan ^{-1}(u)-\sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac 12 \log \left(\frac{u^2+2 u+3}{u^2+1}\right)$$